# Converting dataframe counts into values for box plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, boxplot

I have a dataframe of grades that looks like this:

| Course # | 0 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1801 | 242 | 318 | 222 | 88 |
| 3120 | 75 | 324 | 144 | 30 |
| 1150 | 142 | 295 | 211 | 105 |
| 1811 | 130 | 198 | 265 | 105 |
| 3130 | 45 | 255 | 100 | 24 |

---

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        0: {"1801": 242, "3120": 75, "1150": 142, "1811": 130, "3130": 45},
        4: {"1801": 318, "3120": 324, "1150": 295, "1811": 198, "3130": 255},
        3: {"1801": 222, "3120": 144, "1150": 211, "1811": 265, "3130": 100},
        2: {"1801": 88, "3120": 30, "1150": 105, "1811": 105, "3130": 24},
    }
)
d = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        0: {"1801": 242, "3120": 75, "1150": 142, "1811": 130, "3130": 45},
        4: {"1801": 318, "3120": 324, "1150": 295, "1811": 198, "3130": 255},
        3: {"1801": 222, "3120": 144, "1150": 211, "1811": 265, "3130": 100},
        2: {"1801": 88, "3120": 30, "1150": 105, "1811": 105, "3130": 24},
    }
)
df.index.name = "Course #"
```

I want to create a box plot (probably using `plotly`) of the distribution of those grades, but `plotly.express.box` wants individual values (such as a list of 242 `0`, 318 `4`, etc.).

Is there an easy way to transform the dataframe, or give better input into box plot functions, to graph this data?

---

I solved it brute force this way:

```py
def transform_to_values(s: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    my_dict: dict[str, list[float]] = {}
    for value in s.itertuples():
        my_list: list[float] = []
        my_list.extend([4.0] * value.A)
        my_list.extend([3.0] * value.B)
        my_list.extend([2.0] * value.C)
        my_list.extend([1.0] * value.D)
        my_list.extend([0.0] * value.F)
        my_dict[value.Index] = my_list

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient="index").T

    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already produced a partial solution to you own question, but it still has me a bit puzzled so I'll write up another suggestion. The thing that puzzles me the most is what you're doing to your dataset to achieve your desired format. I would think that following the steps from the answer in [How to expand the number of dataframe rows based on columns titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75673570/how-to-expand-the-number-of-dataframe-rows-based-on-columns-titles) would be the correct approach. I would highly appreciate your feedback on this. Anyway, the following plot is produced by the snippet below which partly builds on the suggestion in the linked post.

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        0: {"1801": 242, "3120": 75, "1150": 142, "1811": 130, "3130": 45},
        4: {"1801": 318, "3120": 324, "1150": 295, "1811": 198, "3130": 255},
        3: {"1801": 222, "3120": 144, "1150": 211, "1811": 265, "3130": 100},
        2: {"1801": 88, "3120": 30, "1150": 105, "1811": 105, "3130": 24},
    }
)
df = df.reset_index()
# df = df.melt(id_vars = 'index')


cols = list(df.columns.difference(['index'], sort=False))
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df[cols].max(axis=1))]
out[cols] = np.where(out[cols].gt(out.groupby('index').cumcount(), axis=0),
                     np.repeat([cols], len(out), axis=0), np.nan
                     )
# out = out.set_index('index')
out = pd.melt(out, id_vars='index', value_vars=df.columns[1:])

px.box(out, y='value', x='index', points='all')
```

Comment: Yes, this code achieves what I was looking for.  I hadn't thought to build the array with `np.where`, good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to transpose your dataframe?

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.box(df.T)
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Notice that your y-axis is in the hundreds; this is for grades / GPA, which should max out at 4.  For instance, the Course # 1801 bar has 318 counts of 4.0, 222 counts of 3.0, 88 counts of 2.0, and 242 counts of 0.0, so the mean value should be: 2.43.