# How to expand the number of dataframe rows based on column titles?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe of the form:

```
  name  0  1  2
0    A  4  2  1
1    B  2  3  4
2    C  1  3  2
```

This is the result of grouping and summarizing data earlier in my real world data process.
What I would like to do now, is to expand (explode?) each row so that each element in that row fills a number of rows corresponding to the column title, except for `name`, so that the dataframe ends up like this:

```
name 0    1    2
------------------
A    0    1    2
A    0    1    nan
A    0    nan  nan
A    0    nan  nan
B    0    1    2
B    0    1    2
B    nan  1    2
B    nan  nan  2
C    0    1    2
C    nan  1    2
C    nan  1    nan
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff with `df.iterrows()` and assigning new columns to an empty dataframe with columns with the lenghts of the `max` of each row and filling up with `nans`, but it ended up buggy and really messy. It would be great if any of you pandas experts could take a look. Thank you for any suggestions!

#### Reproducible dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A','B','C'], 0:[4,2,1], 1:[2,3,3], 2:[1,4,2]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repeat your rows to the maximum number per original row, then use numpy broadcasting to mask the non-needed values:

```
# get list of columns other than name
cols = list(df.columns.difference(['name'], sort=False))

# repeat the rows to the max of each group
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df[cols].max(axis=1))]

# only keep the values < to the number of repeats
out[cols] = np.where(out[cols].gt(out.groupby('name').cumcount(), axis=0),
                     np.repeat([cols], len(out), axis=0), np.nan
                    )
```

Output:

```
  name    0    1    2
0    A  0.0  1.0  2.0
0    A  0.0  1.0  NaN
0    A  0.0  NaN  NaN
0    A  0.0  NaN  NaN
1    B  0.0  1.0  2.0
1    B  0.0  1.0  2.0
1    B  NaN  1.0  2.0
1    B  NaN  NaN  2.0
2    C  0.0  1.0  2.0
2    C  NaN  1.0  2.0
2    C  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Intermediates:

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df[cols].max(axis=1))]
  name  0  1  2
0    A  4  2  1
0    A  4  2  1
0    A  4  2  1
0    A  4  2  1
1    B  2  3  4
1    B  2  3  4
1    B  2  3  4
1    B  2  3  4
2    C  1  3  2
2    C  1  3  2
2    C  1  3  2

out[cols].gt(out.groupby('name').cumcount(), axis=0)
       0      1      2
0   True   True   True
0   True   True  False
0   True  False  False
0   True  False  False
1   True   True   True
1   True   True   True
1  False   True   True
1  False  False   True
2   True   True   True
2  False   True   True
2  False   True  False
```